# jdbcTemplate - queryForList - Invalid Column Type Error

Tags: spring

The table name will be dynamic and need to return the list of objects dynamically. The parameters also dynamic however 4 parameters will be same for any table.

Method name accepts the table name and 4 parameters required to query any table

```
List<?> conversations = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(
         "select * from "+ tableName + " where id=? and userName=? and 
 password=? and tenantId=?" , paramsObjectArray);
```

tableName is a string which comes dynamically
paramsObjectArray is a Object[] which comes dynamically

Currently the query throws invalid column type.

Thanks.

Comment: what's inside `paramsObjectArray`?

Comment: List of strings

Comment: What do you actually put in that array? Show here

Comment: Check my answer

Comment: I have used NamedParameterJdbcTemplate and resolved the problem. https://www.javatpoint.com/spring-NamedParameterJdbcTemplate-example

Answer (score 0):

Your `paramsObjectArray` contains wrong values. It should correspond with the `?` in order declared in your SQL.

It will bind for each `?` the correct value.
Now if one of the values in your `paramsObjectArray` is not what's expected, it will fail.

It could be that `id` in your db is integer, but you are giving it a `String` or `tenantId` - should be an integer I guess, but you are giving `String`.

Read the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html) first.

Comment: I have used NamedParameterJdbcTemplate and resolved the problem. https://www.javatpoint.com/spring-NamedParameterJdbcTemplate-example